# How can you reload Spine.js views when refreshing a page?

Tags: javascript, spine.js

For example, I followed the Spine+Rails tutorial in Spine's docs. It is a basic Rails app that lists Posts to CRUD, but with Spine.js, so it's all async and super fast. That's all great.

However, refreshing the page or manually hitting in a url like `http://spiny.dev/#/posts/5/edit` only loads `#/posts`' content but keeps the url. It looks like...

[image: this]
.

... when it should in fact display an editing view.

How can one set up Spine.js to 'resume' to where it should?

Answer (score 1):

Check your console (cmd+shift+i and then the console tab, or when the dialog pops up press the >= looking icon in the bottom left corner) (this is your new best friend when writing javascript).

You probably have an error that gets thrown like 'Unknown record'. The problem is that you have to fetch your models earlier. Before all the subcontrollers are initialized. At least that's my guess.

Also, shy away from the scaffolding stuff. It gives you too much cleverness and concepts that aren't good for you so early on. Just begin with something basic and refactor as needed so you end up knowing what every bit of code does in the current scaffold code you have.

Comment: I think scaffolding is a great tool to get you started. You see the global concept, best practices and also what is possible to do with the framework. Later on, you just write the code by yourself because you actually **understand** what's going on.

Comment: The scaffolding is different for each framework. In Spine's case (spine-rails gem) the scaffolding was far too complex for such a simple framework. Changes were hard! So in my case I ended up chucking the scaffolding code and started from scratch. That's when Spine started making sense. But to each his own :)